# Убрать тэги из текстового столбца DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

В папке all_file лежит 200 текстовых файлов, где каждый состоит из 1 строчки текста содержащего html-теги.

Код создания data frame:

```
dir_input='/data/home/maksim.ilin/data/all_file/*.txt'
files=glob.glob(dir_input)
df=pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f,header=None,sep='\t') for f in files],ignore_index=True)
```

В результате соединения получается одновекторный data frame info:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 200 entries, 0 to 199
Data columns (total 1 columns):
0    200 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 1.6+ KB
```

Data frame выглядит вот так :[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Удаление тегов:

```
df[0]=df[0].astype(str)
texts=[]
for a in df.iterrows():
    texts.append(BeautifulSoup(a['description']).text)
```

В итоге ошибка:

```
---> 22     texts.append(BeautifulSoup(a['description']).text)
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

### Пример строчки из файла:

```
<p>Приглашается Бренд-менеджер в известную компанию (сеть магазинов бытовой, видео, аудио-техники). </p><p>Требования:<br />Мужчина/женщина, <br />25-40 лет, <br />образование высшее (желательно маркетинг), <br />с опытом работы от 3 лет на позиции бренд-менеджера (в компании, занимающейся бытовой техникой или в очень крупной компании). <br />Обязательно хороший уровень английского (устный и письменный), <br />сильные навыки управления проектами. <br />Сильные презентационные навыки. <br />ПК: MS Office, Power Point – обязательно. </p><p>Обязанности: <br />продвижение бренда компании, <br />маркетинговые исследования, <br />вывод собственных брендов на рынок, <br />имиджевая реклама. </p><p>Условия:<br />Офис в центре. <br />Возможны командировки. </p>
```

Преобразование в текст есть, получается не преобразует. Как правильно? И примет ли `BeautifulSoup` в такой форме данные?

Comment: "Преобразование в текст есть, получается не преобразует" - как понять это высказывание?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы заменить все невложенные теги на пробелы в столбце `0`:

```
df[0] = df[0].str.replace(r'\<[^\>]*\>', ' ')
```

Результат для приведенной в качестве примера строки:

```
In [87]: df[0].str.replace(r'\<[^\>]*\>', ' ').values[0]
Out[87]: ' Приглашается Бренд-менеджер в известную компанию (сеть магазинов бытовой, видео, аудио-техники).   Требования: Мужчина/женщина,  25-40 лет
,  образование высшее (желательно маркетинг),  с опытом работы от 3 лет на позиции бренд-менеджера (в компании, занимающейся бытовой техникой или в о
чень крупной компании).  Обязательно хороший уровень английского (устный и письменный),  сильные навыки управления проектами.  Сильные презентационны
е навыки.  ПК: MS Office, Power Point – обязательно.   Обязанности:  продвижение бренда компании,  маркетинговые исследования,  вывод собственных бре
ндов на рынок,  имиджевая реклама.   Условия: Офис в центре.  Возможны командировки.  '
```

Comment: MaxU, спасибо за изящное решение. Кстати, создание дата фрейма  из нескольких файлов, тоже принадлежит вам, я прост добавил сепаратор, что бы получилось построчно.

Comment: @максимильин, всегда рад помочь :)

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, я не подумал наперёд сможет ли CountVectorizer преобразовать датафрейм в матрицу, на примерах весь текст дают массивом.... ?

Comment: @максимильин, да, просто передавайте объекту `CountVectorizer` столбец DataFrame. Пример: `vect = CountVectorizer(); X = vect.fit_transform(df[0])`

Comment: помогло очень благодарен.